# Нет доступа к CSS (staticfiles)

Tags: django, python-3.x

Ребят подскажите пожалуйста, почему нет доступа к CSS. Ссылку в шаблон правильно подставляет, там и находятся эти css файлы, но при попытке перейти по этой ссылке, получаем Page not found (404).

Подключение в шаблоне:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!— Bootstrap core CSS —>
<link href="{% static "css/bootstrap.min.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">

<!— Custom styles for this template —>
<link href="{% static "css/blog.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">
```

В Settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = 'static'

TEMPLATES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'))
STATIC_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'))
```

Collectstatic сделал.

На выходе в шаблоне:

При переходе PAge not found http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/css/bootstrap.min.css в Urls.py `] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)`

Comment: А у вас debug включен? Staticfiles работает только с ним

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте в файле settings.py `Debug=True`

Если вам нужен деплой проект, то необходимо подключить ваш static-server. Джанго не выполняет таких функций.

Answer (score -2):

У тебя кавычки в кавычках одинаковые.

```html
<link href="{% static "css/bootstrap.min.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">
```

исправь на

```html
<link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Это хорошо, но не критично и причиной проблемы не является (шаблонизатор воспринимает html-код как обыкновенный текст)